# .load() function load the entire page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have use modal for user sign up and its working correctly when user click on register link the modal popup load perfectly now i am making comment box where user can comment on pictures and if user is not login i want to load the same popup modal which is bind with register link some how i am successful but the error is that the load() function load the entire page for me on the same page i am totally confuse. here is my coding .

```
$("#button").click(function(){
                          var user=$("#username").val();
                          var message=$("#form-s-t").val();
                    if(user != ""){
                      if(message != ""){
                            $.ajax({
                                type:"post",
                                url:"retriveing.php",
                                data:"name="+name+"&message="+message+"&action=addcomment",
                                success:function(data){
                                showComment();
                                }
                            });
                           $("#form-s-t").val('');
                      }
                        else {alert("you can not post empty comments");}
                    }
```

Here in else portion i am loading the popup.

```
else{
                            $('.topopup').load("#toPopup");
                            }
                        });
                   });
```

The popup which loads with register link is this.
[image: correct popup]

User which is not login want to comment it load the page twicly and oppositly as shown in picture.

[image: wrong popup]

Comment: If you dont want page reloads use ajax.

Comment: its not about loading the page its about the popup

Comment: ok let me upload the snapshots so will be helpful

Comment: you need to pass an URL to load() method

Comment: I have each an everything on the same page. so i think no need of url

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing https://api.jquery.com/load/ with https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ ( ".load( url [, data ] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )" and ".load( handler(eventObject) )" )

Comment: you are getting the hold new page from the backend. you should get json type data or xml data.

Comment: ok let me check the documentation but if there is another way to load this hidden div by its id than let me know because i found load method helpful.

Comment: can u please show us the register link coding

Comment: yes for sure i am going to show you register link button coding

Comment: <a href="#" class="topopup">Register</a> here is the register link coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of load() function if the model resides in the same page . try to trigger the register link which can be done like that.
Remove the load function in your else portion and just write the code I have give below.

```
 $('.topopup').trigger("click");

.topopup
```

is a id of register link and you want to load this popup when user is not sign in and want to comment. I hope it will work for you. if the model resides in the same page.

Comment: thanks alot its your second answer which is working thanks alot i am really thankful to you.

Comment: and the both questions were about models.

Answer (score 0):

From you screenshot, you send the wrong argument to the server.

```
$('.topopup').load("#toPopup");
// you just load "/#toPopup" page from the server
// and the server return a new page to you
// then jQuery update '.topopup' with the new
// page
```

Comment: oh bro see from the screen shots the problem is with model(popup) not with data comments are coming fit n fine i only want to load the model if user is not login and want to comment

Comment: i have tried this what you have write but is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading an anchor, so the same page is getting injected into the elements with class `.topopup`. Just check your register button's onclick function and use `else { thatFunction(); }` if you want to recreate the same behaviour. [Also try using `retrieving.php` as a filename.]

To clarify: `load("#toPopup")` is equiv. to `load(currentURL+"#toPopup")`. First parameter is an URL string, not a selector string.

Comment: dear #topup exist in the same page and yes register is an anchor but is not working i am confuse why its not working

Comment: Yes there exists an element on your page with id=toPopup. load("#toPopup") doesn't load that element to the front, but loads the page again into your page and jumps to the element with ID toPopup. You need to find an element called <a href="..." onclick="thisFunction();">Register</a> . Maybe this link element has an ID and JQuery is doing things like $("#registerbutton").click(thisFunction). You want to put "thisFunction();" into the else clause. I'm just guessing you didn't write the overlay yourself. It's a JavaScript function bound to the register link's onclick event. Maybe I'm confused ^^

Comment: yeah you are right dear and you explain exactly what i want to do please explaing it with coding like you have describe this one .<a href="..." onclick="thisFunction();">Register</a> but how can i do this with pure jquery when i dont have

Comment: and yes i have use a plugin of for popup

Comment: Go to your HTML file and search for "Register</a>". Check the preceeding tag for the "onclick" keyword and the function associated with it. If it's there we are lucky. Just copy XXX from onclick="XXX" and replace `$('.topopup').load("#toPopup");` with XXX, whatever is there.

Comment: dear i have read each an every thing and is the same what we have to write but showing a wierd behaviour i dont know why its happening dear .but any how thanks for help in register link is the same the id the class is the same but not working i dont know